# What is "Selection State"? Should it be Enabled?

Tags: android, adb, deep-linking, android-deep-link

As per the [document](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations), We can verify our deeplink intent using

```
adb shell pm get-app-links --user cur <package>
```

E.g.

```
adb shell pm get-app-links --user cur com.airbnb.android
```

It will produce

```
  com.airbnb.android:
    ID: 2c62f23a-087a-4c4b-be25-bc02f719dafc
    Signatures: [43:7B:7C:9A:94:6C:3C:E9:F2:49:A4:30:86:14:F5:42:C1:4D:7C:7A:3B:C9:77:89:98:4E:02:47:CD:23:01:FB]
    Domain verification state:
      airbnb.cat: verified
      airbnb.com: verified
      *.airbnb.cat: verified
      ....  more ....
    User 0:
      Verification link handling allowed: true
      Selection state:
        Disabled:
          airbnb.cat
          airbnb.com
          *.airbnb.cat
          *.airbnb.com
          *.airbnb.co.cr
          ....  more ....
```

My question is,

- What is `Selection state`?
- Why is it mostly `Disabled`?
- Should we make it `Enabled`?
- How can we make it `Enabled`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those links that is already verified, we should keep the status as "Disabled", given the user doesn't need to manually "Enabled" them.

But for some link that is not verified, in the case or AirBnB,

Where they are error as below (note the 2 that are having verifications status as `1024`)

```
  com.airbnb.android:
    ID: 2c62f23a-087a-4c4b-be25-bc02f719dafc
    Signatures: [43:7B:7C:9A:94:6C:3C:E9:F2:49:A4:30:86:14:F5:42:C1:4D:7C:7A:3B:C9:77:89:98:4E:02:47:CD:23:01:FB]
    Domain verification state:
      airbnb.cat: verified
      airbnb.com: verified
      *.airbnb.cat: verified
      ....  more ....
      airbnb.ru: 1024
      ....  more ....
      *.airbnb.pt: verified
      *.airbnb.ru: 1024
      *.airbnb.se: verified
```

We can manually enabled them through the process below

[image]

After doing that, when we perform the below again

```
adb shell pm get-app-links --user cur com.airbnb.android
```

It will result as following. Noticed the 2 links are not `Enabled`.

```
  com.airbnb.android:
    ID: 2c62f23a-087a-4c4b-be25-bc02f719dafc
    Signatures: [43:7B:7C:9A:94:6C:3C:E9:F2:49:A4:30:86:14:F5:42:C1:4D:7C:7A:3B:C9:77:89:98:4E:02:47:CD:23:01:FB]
    Domain verification state:
      airbnb.cat: verified
      airbnb.com: verified
      *.airbnb.cat: verified
      ....  more ....
      airbnb.ru: 1024
      ....  more ....
      *.airbnb.pt: verified
      *.airbnb.ru: 1024
      *.airbnb.se: verified
    User 0:
      Verification link handling allowed: true
      Selection state:
        Enabled:
          airbnb.ru
          *.airbnb.ru
        Disabled:
          airbnb.cat
          airbnb.com
          *.airbnb.cat
          *.airbnb.com
          ....  more ....
```

Therefore the answer to the 4 questions

1. What is Selection state? It's the state if the user has manually Enabled the unverified Link
2. Why is it mostly Disabled? Because most of the Verified link doesn't need to be Enabled, and by default all is Disabled anyway.
3. Should we make it Enabled? Only if the user decided to Enable the unverified links
4. How can we make it Enabled? As shown in the diagram above.